# How to pass props if it already has some value passed?

Tags: reactjs

```
  function UpdatePngf(index, id) {
        const [Cards, setCards] = props.value.Cards
        let CardsData = Cards
    
        var CardsObj = {
            link: Cards[index].link,
            icon: Cards[index].icon,
            name: Cards[index].name,
            png: Cards[index].png,
            id: id,
        }
        CardsData[index] = CardsObj
    
        setCards(CardsData)
    }
export const UpdatePng = withUserData(UpdatePngf)
```

this is my function I want to pass props..but how I am supposed to do so??

should I do this way `function UpdatePngf(index, id,props) {}`? or other way

/** @format */

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react'

const UserData = createContext(null)

export const withUserData = (Component) => (props) => {
    return (
        <UserData.Consumer>
            {(value) => <Component {...props} value={value}></Component>}
        </UserData.Consumer>
    )
}

export default UserData
```

This is my userData hoc..

Comment: Can you show `withUserData`?

Answer (score 0):

I saw `index`, `id` also is props. You just update `UpdatePngf`:

```
function UpdatePngf({index, id, ...props}) { ... }
```

And pass props to `UpdatePng` wwhen using it: <UpdatePng id="...." index="..." ...yourProps>

Comment: I am thinking I am doing all it wrong. What you say??

Comment: UpdatePngf({id, index})